# Haskell: How is this formula calculated? `(return (+1)) (Just 10) 10`

Tags: haskell, types, monads, type-inference, applicative

This is about combining two simple arithmetic operators (two partial functions) by Applicative and Monad.
I roughly understood it so far.

```
-- ┌──────────────────────────────────────┐  
-- | instance Applicative ((->) r) where  |                                           
-- |   pure = const                       |                                           
-- |   (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)            |  (1)                                          
-- |   liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)     |                                         
-- |                                      |       
-- | instance Monad ((->) r) where        |                                           
-- |   f >>= k = \r -> k (f r) r          |  (2)                                                                         
-- └──────────────────────────────────────┘

λ> (+) <*> (*2) $ 10  
  -- Type check: 
  (<*>) ::  f     (a -> b) -> f      a  -> f      b
           (-> r) (a -> b) -> (-> r) a  -> (-> r) b
           (r ->   a -> b) -> (r ->  a) -> (r ->  b)
           ---------------    ---------
           (+) ~ f            (*2) ~ g      r ~ x (10)

  -- Actual calcuation: by (1)
  f x (g x) = (+) 10 ((*2) 10) = (+) 10 20 = 30 

λ> (*2) >>= (+) $ 10  -- 30
  -- Type check: 
  (>>=) ::  m     a    ->  a  -> m     b  ->  m     b
           (-> r) a    -> (-> r) a  -> b  -> (-> r) b
           (r  -> a)   -> (a  -> r  -> b) -> (r ->  b)
           ---------      ---------------
           (*2) ~ f       (+) ~ k             r ~ 10

  -- Actual calculation: by (2)
  k (f r) r = (+) ((*2) 10) 10 = (+) 20 10 = 30
```

But when I tried to apply these things to some structure (Maybe), I got stuck on it. (I marked 'HERE' at the end of lines where I got stuck.)

```
-- ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐   
-- | instance Applicative Maybe where               |                                     
-- |     pure = Just                                |                    
-- |     Just f  <*> m       = fmap f m             |                                       
-- |     Nothing <*> _m      = Nothing              |                                      
-- |     liftA2 f (Just x) (Just y) = Just (f x y)  |                                                  
-- |     liftA2 _ _ _ = Nothing                     |                               
-- |     Just _m1 *> m2      = m2                   |                                 
-- |     Nothing  *> _m2     = Nothing              |                                      
-- |                                                |     
-- | instance  Monad Maybe  where                   |                                 
-- |     (Just x) >>= k      = k x                  |                                  
-- |     Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing              |                                      
-- |     (>>) = (*>)                                |                                                            
-- └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

λ> Just 10 >>= return . (+1)   -- Just 11
  -- Type check:
  (>>=) ::  m     a    ->  a  -> m     b  ->  m     b
            ----------     --------------
            Just 10        return . (+1) :: a -> m b  
        so, m ~ Maybe, a ~ Int
  Just 10 >>= return . (+1) :: m     b 
                               Maybe Int 
  
  -- Actual calculation:
  Just 10 >>= return . (+1) = return . (+1) $ 10
                            = Just   . (+1) $ 10
                            = Just 11

λ> Just >>= return (+1) $ 10   -- 11
  -- This is point-free style
     I don't get it.
  -- Type check:
  (>>=) ::  m     a    ->     a  -> m     b  ->  m     b
            ----------        --------------
            (-> a) (Maybe a)  m (a -> a)   <==== HERE! 
                                           I can't derive the correct type. 

  -- Actual calculation:                   <==== and HERE!
  m >>= f   = \x -> f (m x) x              <==== How can this formula be derived?
            = (return (+1)) (Just 10) 10   <==== How can this be calculated?
```

There is point-free style in Monad expression. I don't got it. How can I deduce the type and get the result as in the prior cases of simple arithmetic expressions?

Many thanks.

---

Thanks for your great answer, Nill.  With your help, I could find what was wrong in my thought and code. But I'm still not able to get the final type of `Just >>= return (+1)` correctly. I updated my question and tried to deduce the type of it. I know I'm wrong in my type deduction. Can I get some more help to find the wrong part and to fix that?

```
-- Type check: Incorrect
(>>=) ::  m     a    ->     a  ->  m    b  ->  m     b
         (-> r) a    ->    (-> r)  a -> b  -> (-> r) b
         --------          --------------
         f                 k                  \r -> k (f r) r
         m                 f                  \r -> m (f r) r          
         (-> d) (Maybe d)  (-> r) (n -> n)
     so, a ~ Maybe d
         a ~ n, b ~ n  -- This means a, b, n are all the same type.
                       -- Character a, b can be interchangeable. 
Just >>= return (+1) :: (-> r) b  
                      = (-> r) a          -- by `a ~ b`
                      = (-> r) (Maybe d)  -- by `a ~ Maybe d` 
                                          -- HERE: Is this right?  
                                             Should this be `(-> r) n`?
                      = a -> Maybe b      -- by changing characters
               HERE: WRONG RESULT TYPE??? It must be `a -> a` not `a -> Maybe a` 

-- Actual calcuation:
Moand instance for function (`(-> r)`) type here (I got)
m >>= f = \x -> f (m x) x
        = return (+1) (Just 10) 10
        = return (+1) (Just 10) $ 10
        = const  (+1) (Just 10) $ 10  -- by (1), pure = const
        = (+1) $ 10                   -- 'Just 10' was ignored by 'const (pure)' function.
        = (+) 10 = 11
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
Just >>= return (+1) $ 10
```

`Just` is a function `r -> Maybe r`, so the function monad `((->) r)` is used, giving the reduction as

```
return (1+) (Just 10) 10
```

because that is the definition of `>>=` for the `((->) r)` monad (just as you've given it at the top of your post, `f >>= k = \r -> k (f r) r`).

Now, `return (1+)` is applied to `Just 10`, so it is too a function,

```
return :: Monad m => a          -> m        a
(1+) :: Num m =>   n -> n
return (1+) :: (Monad m, Num n) => m     (n -> n)
                         Num n  => (r -> (n -> n))
Just 10 :: (Num i => Maybe i) ~     r
```

For functions, `return == const`, so we have

```
const (1+) (Just 10) 10
===
(1+) 10
===
11
```

Your other question is, how come for the `((->) r)` monad, `m >>= f = \x -> f (m x) x`? (you did notice that it is the same as that definition at the top, `f >>= k = \r -> k (f r) r`, up to some variables renaming, right?)

And the answer is, because the types fit:

```
(>>=)    ::  m     a  -> (a -> m     b ) -> m     b
         ~   (r -> a) -> (a -> (r -> b)) -> (r -> b)
(>>=)        m           f                   x  = b
    where
        mx = m x       :: a
        f_mx = f mx    ::       r -> b
        b = f_mx x     ::            b
```

---

*edit:* Let's try deriving the type of `Just >>= return (+1)` without any thinking, just in the purely mechanical manner like a compiler would. We'll use the main rule of type derivation, corresponding to the [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) rule in logic:

```
        A     :: a
     F        :: t -> b
    --------------------
     F  A     ::      b       ,  t ~ a
```

The trick is to use all different type variables from the start, so we won't even have a chance of mixing them up:

```
 -- Just >>= return (+1)  ===  (>>=) Just (return (+1))

return      ::  Monad f =>           d    -> f    d
       (+1) ::           Num n =>  n -> n
                         ----------------
return (+1) :: (Monad f, Num n) =>           f (n ->  n)
---------------------------------------------------------
(>>=)  ::    Monad m => m        a -> (a    -> m      b ) -> m      b
      Just  ::          (->) c (Maybe c)
                        ----------------
                 m ~ (->) c , a ~ Maybe c
                 --------------------------
(>>=) Just  ::   Monad ((->) c) => (Maybe c -> (->) c b ) -> (->) c b
             ~   Monad ((->) c) => (Maybe c -> (c ->  b)) -> (c ->  b)
                                   ---------------------- 
return (+1) :: (Monad f, Num n) =>           f (n ->  n)
                                   ---------------------- 
                          f ~ (->) (Maybe c) , (n ->  n) ~
                                               (c ->  b)
(>>=) Just (return (1+)) ::
      (Monad ((->) c), Monad ((->) (Maybe c))  =>             c ->  b
                      ~  Num n                 =>             n ->  n
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. With your help, I could find the wrong part in my thought. 
I should have referenced the monad instance for the `function`, not for `Maybe`.

Comment: I updated my question. The last part of your answer `(>>=)` is definitely right and I got it. But I am still not able to derive the final type of `Just >>= return (+1) :: Num a => a -> a` starting from the type of `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. I know that `m a` should be `r -> Maybe r` or `(-> r) (Maybe r)`. I also know that `a -> m b` should be `m (n -> n)` or `(-> r) (n -> n)`. After substituting alphabetic variables, I got wrong result `a -> Maybe b`, not `a -> a`.

Comment: I finally got it! I owed you so much. Thanks you.